# Is it possible to retrieve a 'time span' from a MongoDB query, using the timestamp within an ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, timestamp, aggregation-framework

We have a basic enquiry management tool that we're using to track some website enquiries in our administration suite, and we're using the ObjectId of each document in our enquiries collection to sort the enquiries by the date they were added.

```js
{
    "_id" :      ObjectId("53a007db144ff47be1000003"),
    "comments" : "This is a test enquiry. Please ignore. We'll delete it shortly.",
    "customer" : {
        "name" :      "Test Enquiry",
        "email" :     "test@test.com",
        "telephone" : "07890123456",
        "mobile" :    "07890123456",
        "quote" :     false,
        "valuation" : false
    },
    "site" : [],
    "test" : true,
    "updates" : [ 
        {
            "_id" :          ObjectId("53a007db144ff47be1000001"),
            "status" :       "New",
            "status_id" :    ObjectId("537de7c3a5e6e668ffc2335c"),
            "status_index" : 100,
            "substatus" :    "New Web Enquiry",
            "substatus_id" : ObjectId("5396bb9fa5e6e668ffc23388"),
            "notes" :        "New enquiry received from website.",
        }, 
        {
            "_id" :          ObjectId("53a80c977d299cfe91bacf81"),
            "status" :       "New",
            "status_id" :    ObjectId("537de7c3a5e6e668ffc2335c"),
            "status_index" : 100,
            "substatus" :    "Attempted Contact",
            "substatus_id" : ObjectId("53a80e06a5e6e668ffc2339e"),
            "notes" :        "In this test, we pretend that we've not managed to get hold of the customer on the first attempt.",
        }, 
        {
            "_id" :          ObjectId("53a80e539b966b8da5c40c36"),
            "status" :       "Approved",
            "status_id" :    ObjectId("52e77a49d85e95f00ebf6c72"),
            "status_index" : 200,
            "substatus" :    "Enquiry Confirmed",
            "substatus_id" : ObjectId("53901f1ba5e6e668ffc23372"),
            "notes" :        "In this test, we pretend that we've got hold of the customer after failing to contact them on the first attempt.",
        }
    ]
}
```

Within each enquiry is an updates array of objects which also have an ObjectId as their main identity field. We're using an `$unwind` and `$group` aggregation to pull the first and latest updates, as well as the count of updates, making sure we only take enquiries where there have been more than one update (as one is automatically inserted when the enquiry is made):

```js
db.enquiries.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "test": true
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$updates"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "latest_update_id": {
                $last: "$updates._id"
            },
            "first_update_id": {
                $first: "$updates._id"
            },
            "update_count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "update_count": {
                $gt: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

This results in the following output:

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a295ad122ea80200000005"),
            "latest_update_id" : ObjectId("53a80bdc7d299cfe91bacf7e"),
            "first_update_id" : ObjectId("53a295ad122ea80200000003"),
            "update_count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53a007db144ff47be1000003"),
            "latest_update_id" : ObjectId("53a80e539b966b8da5c40c36"),
            "first_update_id" : ObjectId("53a007db144ff47be1000001"),
            "update_count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

This is then passed through to our code (node.js, in this case) where we perform a few operations on it and then present some information on our dashboard.

Ideally, I'd like to add another `$group` pipeline aggregation to the query which would subtract the timestamp of `first_update_id` from the timestamp of `latest_update_id` to give us a timespan, which we could then use `$avg` on.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? (Thank you!)

Comment: Currently not available to the aggregation framework. As you seem to know, you can get the timestamp from the ObjectId. So either do this in client code or surrender to mapReduce that can call the function to get the timestamp value. Depends on your output data size. I for one vote for more "math" functions in the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @NeilLunn Using MapReduce wouldn't be the end of the world (this being, as you can probably gather, largely a statistics exercise) as we could schedule it as a one off – it was largely a question to see whether it's possible within the aggregation framework. It'd be nice to be able to access the properties/functions of the ObjectId fields in the queries.

Comment: @abitgone I'm curious, you would group by _id : null to get the average for all documents?

Comment: @ChristianP: Sure, but I need to negate enquiries that don't have 2 or more updates. Additionally, would the average for all documents work on ObjectId fields in such a way that it would preserve the timestamp correctly?

Comment: Your comment is a little bit unclear. You want the average diff for each document or average for all documents?

Comment: Sorry: To be clear, given a collection of documents, I'd like to know the average time between the timestamp in first_update_id and the timestamp in last_update_id, the idea being that we'd like to display the average time it's taken, so far, to deal with an enquiry until it's closed.

Comment: @abitgone see my edit. I think it will answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Neil already pointed out, you can't get to the timestamp from the ObjectId in the aggregation framework.

You said that speed is not important, so using MapReduce you can get what you want:

```
var map  = function() {
    if (this.updates.length > 1) {

        var first = this.updates[0];
        var last = this.updates[this.updates.length - 1];

        var diff = last._id.getTimestamp() - first._id.getTimestamp();

        var val = {
            latest_update_id : last._id,
            first_update_id : first._id,
            update_count : this.updates.length,
            diff: diff 
        }

        emit(this._id, val);
    } 
};

var reduce = function() { };

db.runCommand(
    {
        mapReduce: "enquiries",
        map: map,
        reduce: reduce,
        out: "mrresults",
        query: { test : true}
    }
);
```

This are the results:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a007db144ff47be1000003"),
    "value" : {
        "latest_update_id" : ObjectId("53a80e539b966b8da5c40c36"),
        "first_update_id" : ObjectId("53a007db144ff47be1000001"),
        "update_count" : 3,
        "diff" : 525944000
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get the average diff for all documents you can do it like this:

```
var map  = function() {
    if (this.updates.length > 1) {

        var first = this.updates[0];
        var last = this.updates[this.updates.length - 1];

        var diff = last._id.getTimestamp() - first._id.getTimestamp();

        emit("1", {diff : diff});
    } 
};

var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var reducedVal = { count: 0, sum: 0 };

    for (var idx = 0; idx < values.length; idx++) {
        reducedVal.count += 1;
        reducedVal.sum += values[idx].diff;
    }

    return reducedVal;
};

var finalize = function (key, reducedVal) {
    reducedVal.avg = reducedVal.sum/reducedVal.count;

    return reducedVal;
};

db.runCommand(
    {
        mapReduce: "y",
        map: map,
        reduce: reduce,
        finalize : finalize,
        out: "mrtest",
        query: { test : true}
    }
);
```

And the example output:

```
> db.mrtest.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "value" : {
        "count" : 2,
        "sum" : 1051888000,
        "avg" : 525944000
    }
}
```